# sizeof derived class with virtual base and virtual function

Tags: c++, function, virtual-inheritance

I'm having a problem with C++ virtual inheritance.

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Func(){};
    int BaseValue;
};

class Derived : virtual public Base
{
public:
    void Func(){};
    virtual void Func2(){};
    int DerivedValue;
};
```

Which compiles soundly, however, I'm a little confused about the memory structure.

I wish to have the result of`sizeof(Derived)==20`, namely:

1. **BaseValue and DerivedValue--8 bytes**
2. **Pointer denotes the member offset of Base class** *(feature of virtual inheritance)*--4 bytes
3. **Pointer denotes the virtual function table of Base class--4 bytes**
4. **Pointer denotes the virtual function `Func2()` which only belongs to class Derived--4 bytes** 
   *(as far as I'm concerned, derived class which has no non-virtual base classes and gets its unique virtual functions should has its own virtual table)*

Which sum up to 20 bytes;

yet Xcode 4.6 produces a different result of `sizeof(Derived)==16`, do I get it wrong?

Comment: Yes you got it wrong.  I'm confused because you imply that you know what a virtual function table is, and then in the very next sentence show that you don't know how a virtual function table works.  How do you think a virtual function table works?

Comment: Yeah, I think I know how a virtual function table work, say, if I get an instance b of Base, I can get the address of Func() as (int*)*(&b),

Comment: This is implementation defined and you should avoid relying on such information. For example an int may be 2 bytes (68k anyone?) and the size of a pointer may be something else as well. Now if you are asking because you want to understand the vtable, that's another thing.

Comment: you mean the vtable mechanism is compiler related? or the size of pointers? I assume that in 32 bit environment the pointers are 4 bytes

Comment: I don't know how to properly express the "very next sentence" in English, what I mean is a pointer to denote the offset of the base member(it is BaseValue here)in the memory of an instance of class Derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pointer denotes the virtual function table of Base class--4 bytes
>   Pointer denotes the virtual function Func2() which only belongs to
>   class Derived--4 bytes (as far as I'm concerned, derived class which
>   has no non-virtual base classes and gets its unique virtual functions
>   should has its own virtual table)

Ah, I see the problem now.  That's not *quite* how virtual function tables work.  When `Base` is defined, the compiler notices it requires a virtual table, and generates a virtual table for `Base`, with one pointer (`Func`), which points to the `Base::Func` implementation.  When `Derived` is defined, the compiler notices it inherits from `Base`, and generates a function table for `Base` that has *two* pointers, `Func` points to `Derived::Func`, and `Func2` points to `Derived::Func2`.

Then, if an instance of `Base` is created, it's function table pointer that you mention points at the `Base` table, and any calls to `Func` will be redirected to `Base::Func`.

If an instance of `Derived` is created, it's internal `Base` object's virtual function table pointer will point at the `Derived` table instead.  `Base` only knows how to access the `Func` pointer, but that `Func` pointer points at `Derived::Func` now, and so that's what get's called.  It doesn't realize it's pointing at a different table.  In code, it might look more like this:

```
using voidFunctionType = void(*)();

struct BaseVTable {
    voidFunctionType Func;
}BaseVTableGlobal; 

struct Base {
    Base() :vTable(&BaseVTableGlobal) {}
    void Func() {vTable->Func();}

    BaseVTable* vTable; //4 bytes
    int BaseValue; //4 bytes
}; //total is 8 bytes

struct DerivedVTable : public BaseVTable  {
    voidFunctionType Func;
    voidFunctionType Func2;
}DerivedVTableGlobal; 

//inherits 8 bytes, +4 for virtual inheritance = 12
struct Derived : virtual public Base { 
    Derived() :Base() {vTable = &DerivedVTableGlobal;} //the shared vTable points at DerivedVTableGlobal
    void Func() {vTable->Func();} //base knows about Func, so this is easy
    void Func2() {((DerivedVTable*)vTable)->Func2();} //base doesn't know about Func2

    int DerivedValue; //4 bytes
}; //16 bytes total
```

So XCode is right.  `Derived` is "hijacking" `Base`s virtual function table, and in fact, that's *exactly* how virtual functions do their magic.

(Assumptions everywhere, none of this is well-defined, virtual inheretence complicates things, etc etc etc)

Comment: OK, I see what I misunderstand, maybe I should check on it. I thought this happens only if the base class is non-virtural so as to add Func2 to the vtable inherited, otherwise, it should get a new virtual pointer if it gets a virtual function not appear in its base class

Comment: Ghostblade, nope, even if `Derived` inherits from `Base` virtually, it still overrides `Base`'s virtual pointer.  Otherwise, the virtual functions would fail wouldn't they?